# Xamarin and identityserver4 authentication error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth, xamarin.android, identityserver4

My project is developed using VS2017 and Xamarin.
I want to authenticate my Xamarin android mobile app using IdentityServer4.

My IdentityServer4 client information is like this:

```
    {
        "Enabled": "true",
        "ClientId": "xamarin.android",
        "ClientName": "Application",
        "UserClaims": ["role"],
        "RequirePkce": "true",
        "AllowOfflineAccess": "true",
        "RequireClientSecret": "false",
        "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": "true",
        "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": "true",
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [
          "authorization_code"
        ],
        "RedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost/oauth/grants"
        ],
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "openid",
          "profile",
          "offline_access",
          "my.api"
        ]
    }
```

And my xamarin App class is like following.

```
    [assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    namespace MainUI
    {
        public partial class App
        {
            public App() : this(null) { }

            public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

            protected override async void OnInitialized()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
            }


            public static Account AuthAccount { get; set; }
            public static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

            protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
            {
                containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
                containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
            }

            protected override void OnStart()
            {
                var oAuth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    "xamarin.android",
                    "offline_access my.api",
                    new Uri("http://localhost/oauth/connect/authorize"), 
                    new Uri("http://localhost/oauth/grants"))
                {
                    AccessTokenUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/oauth/connect/token"),
                    ShouldEncounterOnPageLoading = false
                };

                var presenter = new OAuthLoginPresenter();
                presenter.Login(oAuth);

            }   
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code, throws an exception that has no details.

[image]

Error Stacktrace is like this:

> at Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter.Login
>   (Xamarin.Auth.Authenticator authenticator) [0x00012] in
>   <98de59c6304c4348ab7c355151c2702f>:0    at MainUI.App.OnStart ()
>   [0x0004f] in C:\Development\Proj\MainUI\MainUI\App.xaml.cs:64

Have you ever get the error like this?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I updated the post for stack trace.

Comment: Did you initialize Presenter in MainActivity? [oauth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#presenting-the-sign-in-user-interface)